# Laravel Envoy Error: Was not Expected at This Time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-envoy

I have tried to use Laravel Envoy, but when I run `envoy run deploy` I get the following error message:

> [x.x.x.x]: << was not expected at this time.

**Envoy.blade.php**

```
@servers(['web' => 'x.x.x.x'])

@task('deploy', ['on' => 'web'])
    ls
@endtask
```

**My Env**

```
Windows 7 (x64)
PHP 5.4.22 (cli) (built: Nov 13 2013 21:17:59)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by ionCube Ltd.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Envoy only works on Linux or OSX, not Windows.

See: http://laravel.com/docs/ssh#envoy-task-runner

> Note: Envoy requires PHP version 5.4 or greater, and only runs on Mac / Linux operating systems.

Comment: There is an alternative to Envoy which works on Windows and is very similar to Envoy. It's called Deployer and can be found at http://deployer.org/

Answer (score 0):

try expliciting the user name

like

> @servers(['web' => 'user@x.x.x.x'])